# If Specific Post, Link Elsewhere

Tags: posts, loop, conditional-content

I would like to create a conditional statement that checks the loop for a specific post ID, then if true, it outputs a link elsewhere.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=team&orderby=title&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post grid" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="plus-sign">

                <!-- If team post 'You' send user to the careers page -->
                <?php if ( is_singular( '2295' ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="/careers" title="T+K Careers"><?php the_post_thumbnail('team-thumb'); ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('team-thumb'); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
            <div class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why not `if ( 2295 === get_the_ID() )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your check didn’t work is because `is_singular()` checks for **post types**, not for **post IDs**.

`is_singular( 'product' )` checks if the current post is of the type `product`, nothing else.

The comparison `2295 === get_the_ID()` does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@toscho was correct.

I replaced this:

```
<?php if ( is_singular( '2295' ) ) : ?>
```

With this:

```
<?php if ( 2295 === get_the_ID() ) : ?>
```